# Преобразование типов в функции

Tags: c, stm32, embedded

Возвращаемое значение этой функции `uint32_t`:

```
int32_t IKS01A2_MOTION_SENSOR_GetAxes(uint32_t Instance, uint32_t Function, IKS01A2_MOTION_SENSOR_Axes_t *Axes);
```

его надо записать в следующую функцию параметром `uint8_t *pData`:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_UART_Transmit(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
```

Если написать так, то возникает конфликт типов:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_UART_Transmit(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, (IKS01A2_MOTION_SENSOR_GetAxes()), uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
```

Я хочу выполнить преобразование из `uint32_t` возвращаемого значения первой функции в `uint8_t`. Как я могу выполнить преобразование типов в данном случае без переписывания самих функций?

Comment: "Возвращаемое значение этой функции uint32_t". Нет, возвращаемое значение этой функции `int32_t`. Не замечаете разницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, не может быть никакого осмысленного "преобразования типов" между типами `int32_t` и `uint8_t *`. Хоть вы этого и не объяснили, в данном случае речь идет скорее всего о *реинтерпретации памяти* объекта типа `int32_t` как массива `uint8_t`.

Во-вторых, не ясно, что у вас вообще за чушь написана в "Если написать так, то возникает конфликт типов". У вас там даже не вызов функции написан, а какая-то бессмысленная синтаксическая каша. Проблемы с приведенным вами кодом не имеют никакого отношения ни к какому "конфликту типов".

---

Для того, чтобы вызвать функцию `HAL_UART_Transmit` с указателем на результат `IKS01A2_MOTION_SENSOR_GetAxes` вам придется сначала сохранить результат вызова функции в объекте типа `int32_t`, как показано в ответе @HolyBlackCat. Более того, используя *составные литералы* вы можете даже сделать это "в одну строчку"

```
HAL_UART_Transmit(..., (uint8_t *) &(int32_t) { IKS01A2_MOTION_SENSOR_GetAxes() }, ...)
```

хотя лучше все таки не лепить все в одну строчку.

Comment: Можно узнать ваше мнение на счет законности `(uint8_t *) &(int32_t) { ... }`? Мне кажется, что это нарушение strict aliasing rule, потому что `uint8_t` не обязательно является символьным типом.

Comment: @eanmos: Хороший вопрос... Стандарт языка, насколько я знаю, впрямую такого разрешения не дает. Можно разве лишь что-то дедуцировать: 1) данная платформа предоставляет тип `uint8_t`, т.е. адресуемая единица памяти занимает не более 8 бит, 2) минимальный размер типа `char` 8 бит и он должен соответствовать минимальной адресуемой единице. Из чего можно сделать вывод, что `uint8_t` должен совпадать с `unsigned char` хотя бы по преставлению. Но теоретически, есть вероятность, что за `uint8_t` скрывается какой-то расширенный целочисленный тип.

Answer (score 1):

Проще сделать не в одну строчку, а в две:

```c
int32_t x = IKS01A2_MOTION_SENSOR_GetAxes(...);
HAL_UART_Transmit(..., (uint8_t *)&x, ...);
```

Comment: А не нарушается ли тут strict aliasing?

Comment: @eanmos Нет, через `char` и `unsigned char` можно читать/писать куда угодно.

Comment: Но ведь не факт, что `uint8_t` это typedef на `unsigned char`. Я понимаю, что это мало вероятно, но все же. Как к этому относится стандарт?

Comment: @eanmos Как-то не интересовался; наверное будет UB. Можно задать новый вопрос, если интересно. :)

Comment: Я тоже только сейчас задумался :) Немного поискав информацию нашел вот [это](https://gist.github.com/jibsen/da6be27cde4d526ee564). Так что да, если `uint8_t` не символьный тип, то это UB.